# Custom sorting method of QTableView?

Tags: qt4, qtableview, qt4.7, qstandarditemmodel

How can I setup custom sorting method for a QTableView , or for the model ?
(Which function should I re-implement)

The default sorting algorithm are for strings , I want a number sorting method for some specific column.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html). You should reimplement lessThan method. Then you have to set sourceModel for your proxy model, and set your proxy model as model for your view

```
class MyProxyModel: public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
protected:
     bool   lessThan ( const QModelIndex & left, const QModelIndex & right ) const
     {
         // your sorting rules
     }
};

// ... somewhere where your view is accessible
MyProxyModel * m = new MyProxyModel();
m->setSourceModel(yourModel);
yourView->setModel(m);
```