# Sorting QTableWidget by column

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget and I want to sort the components of this table according to the values of the zero column, I used this code :

```
ui->tableParticle->sortByColumn(0,Qt::AscendingOrder);
```

but it gives no good results, the image below shows you the problem I sought solution but found nothing, sorry I can't put all the code because it's very long.

[image]

Comment: I also used :  ui->tableParticle->sortItems(0,Qt::AscendingOrder); and it does not work .

Comment: "* I can't put all the code because it's very long*" is exactly the reason you're encouraged to create a [mcve] of your problem.  I'd expect it to be around 10-20 lines.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I add that before setItem and it's work :

```
ui->table->horizontalHeader()->sortIndicatorOrder();
```

Answer (score 3):

By deafault QTableWidget sorts columns as ordinary strings. If you search for questions like "custom sorting in QTableWidget", you will find solutions to your answer, e.g.

1. [Custom sorting method of QTableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839116/custom-sorting-method-of-qtableview)
2. [Custom Sorting in QTableWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648215/custom-sorting-in-qtablewidget)

Comment: My table widget inherits from QStyledItemDelegate not QTableWidget, also i see the answers and i dont understand very well because im new in Qt and C++, I see that i should reimplement operator<(), but i dont understand  how  to subclass the QTableWidgetItem, i need to create a new class or change my class who creates the table ?

Comment: I add that to my code but it dosn't work :    <br/>                                            class Item: public QTableWidgetItem   <br/>
{

 public:

     bool operator < (const QTableWidgetItem &other) const
     {
         // TODO: To be safe, check weather conversion to int is possible.
         return (this->text().toInt() < other.text().toInt());
     }

 };

Answer (score 2):

I find also this answer add by *SoloPilot*, but i dont know how the pad the number strings with blanks and when I will add the line ('    '+numStr)[-4:]  :

**The answer**

One way that worked in my situation was

1. before filling the table, turn off sorting:

---

```
table.setSortingEnabled(False)
```

---

2. pad the number strings with blanks and make all strings in the column have the same length:

---

```
('    '+numStr)[-4:]
```

---

3. after filling the table, turn on sorting:

---

```
table.setSortingEnabled(True)
```

---

This fixed the row sorting problem and the numerical order.